# Accessing Webcam Streams Through Shell

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, webcam, video-streaming

I am writing an app (running on ARM Ubuntu) that needs to be able to do image processing on the video stream from a webcam. The easiest way that I can get the data is through the output stream on a process, so I am planning to host a child process, run a command, and consume the output. My current plan is to use FFMPEG, but I can use any command-line tool that works on ARM.
There are really two parts to my question:

1. What FFMPEG (or other utility, if there is a better one) command do I need to use from the command line to get a stream of pixel data from a webcam?
2. What format will the output be in (preferably just RGB data, no encodings or headers)? I am going to need to parse it in my app and need to know the encoding format.

Any information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

With FFmpeg and `video4linux2`, you can [get almost any webcam input](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input). Make sure to use a recent version of `ffmpeg` from [the download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or by [compiling yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide). Your camera frame sizes and framerates can be checked with:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

For example, if you found out what framerate and picture size your webcam delivers:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
-c:v rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -
```

This would capture 25fps video at 640×480 pixels from the camera at `/dev/video0` and output raw YUV frames encoded with the YUV 4:2:0 planar pixel format to stdout. The `rawvideo` encoder and format takes care of that. There will be no headers.

What you can change here:

- Set a different framerate or -size.
- Here, the `-` at the end sends the data to stdout, but you can choose a file as well if you want to.
- To see what other pixel formats are available, run `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`. Their byte order is explained on [fourcc.org](http://fourcc.org/). If you really want RGB data (although I doubt this is the default your camera outputs), you can use `-pix_fmt rgb24`, for example.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. But shouldn't I see something in the terminal when I run it? I haven't tried it in my app yet, but shouldn't I see something?

Comment: Yes, you should see something. If you don't get any output maybe it couldn't find the webcam. Depends on your setup – if you can paste the full uncut console output somewhere we could check.

Comment: Here's the output... not very exciting: http://pastebin.com/Z2hWV1uL

Comment: I was able to capture a single image with a different utility, so I know the webcam works as /dev/video0

Comment: You're using a terribly outdated version of `ffmpeg`. As I mentioned in my post, please download a recent one. The one you have is actually not even from FFmpeg but a fork that released it under the wrong name.

Comment: Wow... OK, thanks; I'll try that as soon as I can. I am doing this on a small embedded computer (headless system), so I never really thought that it might not be right. (I know, stupid assumption!)

Comment: You might not be able to answer this, but how can I find or build FFMPEG and it's encoders on an ARM-based Ubuntu computer? I tried with various guides that I found but all of them threw errors somewhere in the process. Shouldn't something like a clone (of the repo) and then a make work?

Answer (score -1):

Definitely check out VLC's command line options.  I'm not really familiar with it's output streams but I seem to have read that it could do pretty much what you're trying to do.

[VLC homepage](http://videolan.org)